# ipywidgets clear_output() does not work the second time it's used

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I am experiencing a weird behavior with the `Output` widget from `ipywidgets`. I replicate it with the below code in a jupyter notebook:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def clear_output():
    change_output_button = widgets.Button(description="Change output?")
    the_output = widgets.Output()
    clear_output_widget = widgets.VBox([change_output_button, the_output])
    clear_output_widget.click_count = 0

    def button_clicked(_button):
        clear_output_widget.click_count += 1
        the_output.clear_output()
        the_output.append_stdout(f"button clicked {clear_output_widget.click_count} times.")

    change_output_button.on_click(button_clicked)

    return clear_output_widget
```

In another cell, I input

```
clear_output()
```

which displays the button as intended.

Below are the sequence of outputs I get:

- click 1

```
button clicked 1 times.
```

- click 2

```
button clicked 1 times.button clicked 2 times.
```

- click 3

```
button clicked 3 times.
```

- click 4

```
button clicked 4 times.
```

and so on...

I do not understand the click 2 behavior. Am I doing something wrong?

Below is my *About Jupyter Notebook* info:

Server Information:
You are using Jupyter notebook.

The version of the notebook server is: **6.0.1**
The server is running on this version of Python:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:22:51) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Current Kernel Information:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:22:51) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be due to using `append_stdout` rather than the context manager. Probably a buffering problem.

In the meantime you can do:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets


def clear_output():
    change_output_button = widgets.Button(description="Change output?")
    the_output = widgets.Output()
    clear_output_widget = widgets.VBox([change_output_button, the_output])
    clear_output_widget.click_count = 0

    def button_clicked(_button):
        clear_output_widget.click_count += 1
        the_output.clear_output()
        with the_output:
            print(f"button clicked {clear_output_widget.click_count} times.")


    change_output_button.on_click(button_clicked)

    return clear_output_widget
```

Comment: thanks, this solves the problem indeed! I assume you're a contributor to the project. I'll be watching for a bug fix and in the meantime I will use this trick.

Comment: Always a pleasure, I'm not a contributor but it seems to be a fairly simple issue. I'll try to submit a PR if I can understand what is going on.

Comment: I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2584) on github. It seems that `append_output` is the culprit.

Comment: Yes, the clear_output is using Jupyter's display mechanism, and append_stdout is not. I think there is room for improvement here (can discuss on github).